# What is the name of the UWP repository?

Tags: c#, uwp, repository, open-source

Wikipedia states that the

> Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is an open source API created by Microsoft

but I had no luck finding it (always landing in the docs or other tutorials). I'd like to take a look at the `LockScreen` class.

Do you know its location or the name of the repository?

Comment: I guess that article is outdated, or not properly citated. The linked resource links to the [current design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/design-and-ui-intro), whereas the [current header site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) neither states that it's open source. Maybe that statement about "open source" is just not true any more.

Comment: @Herdo it looks like you're right and it's a mistake on wiki. I've just found [this](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/7989744-make-universal-windows-platform-open-source-and-cr) page where people vote for making it open-source.

Comment: There is [an open source project](https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/) for interfacing with UWP, but the implementation is not open.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you were looking for, but this may help you-

**UWP sample collection-**

[Windows Universal Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples)

**LockScreenApps Repository-**

[Lock Screen App Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/LockScreenApps)

Both are hosted in GitHub. (LockScreenApps is a part of UWP sample collection.)

Comment: I was asking for a repository because I was interested in the implementation of the `LockScreen` class and I thought that _source-code_ is implied ;-) sorry for the confustion. I wanted (still want) to find out how it is changing the lock-screen-background as I cannot find any _official_ Windows API for that.